# Show that $\alpha$ $(G)$ $\le$ $\frac {|V(G)|}2$

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a k-regular graph with $k$ $\ge$ $1$, then show that  $\alpha$ $(G)$ $\le$ $\frac {|V(G)|}2$.

$\alpha$ $(G)$ : The independence number of graph

|V(G)|          : The number of vertice

If I draw the $k-regular$ graph and indentify the independent number, I  will find that $\alpha$ $(G)$ $=$ $\frac {|V(G)|}2$. I still try with $k= 2,3$. Maybe someone can help me to show that $\alpha$ $(G)$ $\le$ $\frac {|V(G)|}2$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A\subseteq V(G)$ be an independent set with $|A|=\alpha(G),$ and let $B=V(G)\setminus A.$ Let $m$ be the number of edges between $A$ and $B.$ Can you show that $m=k|A|$? Can you show that $m\le k|B|$?

Comment: @Angelo Meaning that you don't see why $m=k|A|,$ or that you don't see why $m\le k|B|,$ or that you don't see why $|A|\le\frac{|V(G)|}2$ follows from $m=k|A|$ and $m\le k|B|$?

Comment: From $m=k|A|$ and $m\le k|B|$ we get $k|A|\le k|B|$. Since $k\gt0$ we can cancel $k$ and get $|A|\le|B|.$ Since $B=V(G)\setminus A$ we have $|B|=|V(G)|-|A|,$ so $|A|\le|V(G)|-|A|.$ Adding $|A|$ to both sides of the last inequality, we get $2|A|\le|V(G)|.$ Dividing by $2,$ we get $|A|\le\frac{|V(G)|}2.$ Since $|A|=\alpha(G),$ it follows that $\alpha(G)\le\frac{|V(G)|}2.$